# JSON youtube data return

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, youtube

I'm having an issue not sure if it's lack of sleep or skill but I have my script everything works but, the commentCount part of my code I've tried everything I can think of to get this to return the commentCount value but all I get is undefined. any help would be grateful.

```
 function getYouTubeVideoInfo() {
                $.ajax({
                        url: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/<?php echo $_GET['v']; ?>?v=2&alt=json",
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        success: function (data) { parseresults(data); }
                });
        }

        function parseresults(data) {    
var ccount = data.entry.yt$statistics.commentCount;
```

I have also tried the below because I see it under this child on this page but did not work
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference?csw=1#youtube_data_api_tag_entry

```
var ccount = data.entry.yt$channelStatistics.commentCount;
```

Comment: What do you see in your console when you console.log(data) within parseresults function() ?

Comment: When I for example look at http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/O_Et0L_4vJU?v=2&alt=json I do not see yt$channelStatistics in the JSON.

Comment: Correction its under gd$comments > gd$feedLink >countHint : 68

Comment: Ok, and when you use this structure? So: ccount = parseInt(data.entry.gd$comments.gd$feedLink.countHint, 10)?

Comment: that works thank you. needed the parseInt. thanks

Comment: Try to console.log every level in the Json. So console.log(data), console.log(data.entry), console log(data.entry.gd$comments) etc. At which level you first see undefined in your console?